# Polymer paper-input scroll issue

Tags: polymer

I have boiled my small problem down to the following example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'></script>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html'>
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id='base-page'>
        <template>
            <div style='overflow-y:scroll; height:200px'>
                <div style='height:2000px'>
                    <paper-input pattern='[0-9]*' required auto-validate error-message='Input is required' value='dummy'></paper-input> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'base-page'
        });
    </script>
    <base-page></base-page>
</body>
```

The problem is that if I scroll down, the "Input is required" error message does not scroll with the rest of the paper-input. What could be the issue?

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen this happen, but trying your code in a bin, it seems that the problem is that the `paper-input-error`'s position is set as `absolute` by default, if you set it to `relative` using the `--paper-input-error` mixin you should get the desired result.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yakosizisa/edit?html,output) for it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks ... I'll add it as a potential defect for the paper-input